# Testing Spring Singleton implementation using Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, singleton

We had come across an issue in our code, due to a bean which was implemented as a singleton but was not stateless. Due to which, when there are multiple requests (web service) triggered at the same time, there are exceptions and does not return the proper response.

Could this have been caught using Junit? If so, how do we use Junit for the same?  If not, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: JUnit alone, no. JUnit + Sprint Test, maybe.

Comment: Shouldn't you consider keeping the scope as prototype? if not why please explain I am newbie.

Comment: @pathfinder2104 yes, it should be prototype since the bean will maintain state. But the question is if this problem could have been spotted in development stage by using JUnit. And the answer is: it would depend on the kind of integration tests you apply to your project.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanx for explanation ... :) :) I would be looking for the actual answer too, as it may help me in my future development :)

Comment: @pathfinder2104 there is no concrete answer. You may design the best test cases for your components, but there is always one case you didn't even imagine it could exists, and that single specific case appears in production environment and blows up all your work =\. You can only prevent most of the cases to happen by covering your components with unit testing and integration testing. That's why in my first comment I said: maybe.

Comment: This is a flat out design flaw.  The way junit catches this is the developer gives their code to a peer reviewer who realizes the mistake that's been made and then writes a test that proves it's broken.  There isn't really a test you'd write for this if you didn't already suspect a problem.

Comment: @CandiedOrange It is indeed a design flow. And yea that's how junit catches it. But wouldn't writing a test (not specific to this case, but something which could be applied everywhere) prevent such design flaws in the future? That is what I'm after..

Comment: You want something to enforce a rule such as "Singletons shall not have state"?  Sounds like a job for a static code analysis tool or maybe just a coding standards document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the problem is suspected junit can be used to prove the problem is real but it is not suited for enforcing the best practice being violated here.

"Singletons shouldn't have state."

That's a sentence more at home in a coding standards document and perhaps enforced with a static code analysis tool.

Trying to prove that something DOESN'T have any concurrency issues by throwing threads at it is next to impossible.  If you do, and you get lucky, you might prove it does have problems.  You'll never prove it doesn't.

Much better to know and follow best practices and get some one else to look over your code.

Actually I'm not 100% sure singletons should never have state.  But when they do they'd better be synchronized or immutable if they are being shared across threads.

Answer (score 3):

You can use threads with JUnit, just fire up a couple of background threads to invoke the service concurrently, and then invoke the service on the main thread and see if the test passes or not. Personally, I've used this approach to test e.g. (optimistic/pessimistic) locking. However, I'd say this is not a particularly reliable method in pinpointing most concurrency issues.

A better alternative is to use a load testing tool, such as SoapUI or JMeter, and invoke the web service with multiple concurrent consumers, preferably for longer period of time, and see if this generates errors.

In either case, you have to plan for these types of test, i.e.anticipate concurrency problems.

Edit: code review (by people with good experience in concurrency) is also a very effective means of catching concurrency issues. Static code analysis may also help in particular cases, but I would not bet on it alone.